# Precision error on matrix multiplication

Tags: c#, matrix, floating-point, double, precision

Coding a matrix multiplication in my program, I get precision errors (inaccurate results for large matrices).

Here's my code. The current object has data stored in a flattened array, row after row. Other matrix B has data stored in a flattened array, column after column (so I can use pointer arithmetic).

```
protected double[,] multiply (IMatrix B)
{
    int columns = B.columns;
    int rows = Rows;
    int size = Columns;

    double[,] result = new double[rows,columns];
    for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
    {
       for (int col = 0; col < columns; col++)
       {
           unsafe
           {
               fixed (float* ptrThis = data)
               fixed (float* ptrB = B.Data)
               {
                   float* mePtr = ptrThis + row*rows;
                   float* bPtr = ptrB + col*columns;
                   double value = 0.0;
                   for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                   {
                       value += *(mePtr++) * *(bPtr++);
                   }
                   result[row, col] = value;
               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Actually, the code is a bit more complicated : I do the multiply thing for several chunks (so instead of having i from 0 to size, I go from localStart to localStop), then sum up the resulting matrices.

My problem : for a big matrix I get precision error :

```
NUnit.Framework.AssertionException: Error at (0,1)
    expected: <6.4209571409444209E+18>
     but was: <6.4207619776304906E+18>
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Maybe use of the `precision` tag should automatically open up that web page about floating point maths that often crops up in these questions?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps all you have to do is use [Kahan summation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). But you can [never expect](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) to get *exactly* a specific result with floating-point math.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it was just ... a bug. Ended up that instead of having :

```
float* mePtr = ptrThis + row*rows;
float* bPtr = ptrB + col*columns;
```

The correct indexers for my rows were :

```
float* mePtr = ptrThis + row * size;
float* bPtr = ptrB + col * size;
```

Sorry for that, not really fancy answer here. But thanks for the  help !

Answer (score 1):

I originally stated that you should convert the `floats` to `doubles`. However, as you point out that will break your algorithm.

You could try:

```
value += (double)*(mePtr++) * (double)*(bPtr++);
```

A problem with your code as it now stands is that the multiplication is being done in `float` precision then added to a `double`. Casting to `double` first will help to some extent.

It might be clearer to use intermediate `double` variables - but that's up to you.

If this doesn't give you the desire accuracy then you'll need to consider using `decimal` instead of `double`. However, this may result in a performance hit so do some benchmarks first.

Comment: Yeah, but converting mePtr and bPtr to double, can I still use mePtr++ or will this make use of only half the elements of my array ? b.data is float[], if mePtr is a double pointer to b.data[0], won't mePtr++ be 8 bytes on the right, so b.data[2] instead of b.data[1] ?

Comment: @Wam - In that case you'll have to cast the values to double in the calculation - I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

Hem, it doesn't really solve your problem but in NUnit, you can allow to have a precision error and choose the value of this epsilon

Answer (score 0):

As a starting point, use `double` everywhere instead of `float`.

Comment: My arrays are already float[], can't change anything to that. Memory issues at some point, whole application using float[] etc..

Comment: Then I'm not sure that there's much you can do. You've thrown away precision; there's no amount of cleverness that will get it back.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you should be using doubles throughout.  Floats are very imprecise.

Comment: Well, floats are less precise than doubles, that's for sure.  But all (well, approximately all, my statistic is inaccurate) floating-point numbers are imprecise.

Comment: @High, doubles have 29 more bits of precision than floats. This makes them about 100 million times more precise.

Comment: @Marcelo -- it sure does.  And still lots of us doing serious number crunching have to worry about the loss of precision in long running computations.  Changing floats to doubles only postpones the problem it doesn't remove it.  Of course, sometimes it postpones the problem until after the computation finishes.

Answer (score 0):

This is a phenomenon called "Matrix Creep" which happens gradually during matrix manipulations if you don't consistently normalize your matrices.